# I am receiving blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector. What does it mean and what can I do to avoid it?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, shutdown

This is the error shown after I shutdown:

[image]

I am new at using linux, and I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04. I use Ubuntu via a external HDD(WD 1TB). The HDD is two years old.

Recently this error has been popping whenever I shutdown and the OS too is lagging.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`, and the `Disks` application **SMART Data & Tests** data window. This window is scrollable and may require two screenshots. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good indicator of a failure in your hard drive.  You can run the [smart tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) to help confirm this, but you should probably try to ensure that you have a good backup of your data, and plan on looking for a new drive.